# Issue with Broadcast Receiver sending broadcast on response of Retrofit 2 call from a service to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, service, broadcastreceiver, retrofit2

Here is the code where I am sending the broadcast, I am making changes to the local database table here and then sending the broadcast:

```
for (int i = 0; i < forms.length(); i++) {
 retrofit2.Call<SubmitFormResponse> call;
 call = RetrofitClass.getInstance().getWebRequestsInstance().formSubmitWitoutImages(tinyDB.getString(Constants.token), bodyRequest);

 call.enqueue(new Callback<SubmitFormResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<SubmitFormResponse> call, Response<SubmitFormResponse> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            formIds.add(formId);
                            QueueModel model = databaseHandler.getQueueIncidenceStateOnIncidenceID(task_id);
                            model.setNumSubmitted(++numSubmitted);
                            databaseHandler.updateQueuedIncidenceStateOnRunId(model);
//                            updateUI.updateUI(databaseHandler.getAllQueuedIncidences());
                            UploaderService.this.sendBroadcast(new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<SubmitFormResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
}
```

On receiving the broadcast, I am taking the list from the updated database table and then re initialising the adapter with notifyDataSetChanged(), in the fragment. Here is the code for receiving the broadcast:

```
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("CALLED", "Intent passed");

//            pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(true);
            if (adapter != null) {
                list = databaseHandler.getAllQueuedIncidences();
                if (list.size() == 0) {
                    tvNoPendingUploads.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    rvPendingUploads.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    tvNoPendingUploads.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    rvPendingUploads.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    adapter.setItems(list);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else {

                list = databaseHandler.getAllQueuedIncidences();
                Log.e("Up", databaseHandler.getAllQueuedIncidences().size() + "");

                if (list.size() == 0) {
                    tvNoPendingUploads.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    rvPendingUploads.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    tvNoPendingUploads.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    rvPendingUploads.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    adapter = new AdapterPendingUploads(list, getActivity());
                    rvPendingUploads.setLayoutManager(manager);
                    rvPendingUploads.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
//            pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);

        }
    };
```

The receiver is registered in onCreateView() and unregistered in onDestroy():

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pending_uploads, container, false);

        init(view);
        clickListeners();
        getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                BROADCAST_ACTION));
        return view;
    }

@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

The sendBroadcast() is not calling the onRecieve() of BroadcastReceiver immediately, rather it is waiting for the loop to end, with sendBroadcast() been called for n-times and at the end the onRecieve() is called for n-times, continuously.I need to update the UI after hitting each API. The sendBroadcast() and onRecieve() should be called simultaenously after hitting each API.
Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

[EDIT] Using EventBus instead of BroadcastReciever solved the issue but I am still curious as to why is BroadcastReciever showing such behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can try use EventBus library.